# SQLException Must declar scalar variable "@variableName"

Tags: c#, sqlexception, scalar

I am having some trouble trying to update database at a specific row, I am receiving the error `Must declare scalar variable "@lvl"`. Not quite sure what I am supposed to do. Do I need to declare value within my SQL Statement?

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GridViewCellInfo grd = (GridViewCellInfo)radGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[0];
    string lvl = grd.Value.ToString(); 

    string sqlPatientCmd =
        @"UPDATE MotorTB
          SET RightColumn = @RightColumnCB, LeftColumn =  @leftColumnCB
          WHERE (Level = @lvl)";
    SqlConnection connString = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=MERCURY\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=AsiaDB; Integrated Security=SSPI;User ID=MERCURY\Sophie;");
    try {
        connString.Open();

        SqlCommand sqlCmdStatement = new SqlCommand(sqlPatientCmd, connString);

        GridViewCellInfo grid;
        grid = (GridViewCellInfo)radGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[1];
        string rightColVal = grid.Value.ToString();

        grid = (GridViewCellInfo)radGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[2];
        string leftColVal = grid.Value.ToString();

        sqlCmdStatement.Parameters.AddWithValue("@rightColumnCB", rightColVal);
        sqlCmdStatement.Parameters.AddWithValue("@leftColumnCB", leftColVal);
        sqlCmdStatement.ExecuteScalar();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
    }

    // Close the connection
    try {
        connString.Close();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: The error message tells you exactly how to solve the problem...

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to add the lvl var as SqlParamter

```
sqlCmdStatement.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lvl", lvl);
```

Comment: Thanks. It worked I tried it before, but got the same error. I changed my SQL Statement to:

Comment: I can't see the new statement.

Answer (score 1):

@lvl needs to be supplied as a parameter or otherwise defined in the query.